# how can i convert array of eight numbers '0' and '1' characters to byte in c#

Tags: c#

I have a character array include '0' and '1'
how can convert that to byte data type in c#?

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};
```

Comment: did you mean to convert 8 `1` and `0` into one single byte? If so; the closure of the question is premature and [edit] the question to be more explicit. It might be reopend if you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with the use of `Convert` as well

```
char[] chars = new char[] { '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1' };

string binaryString = string.Join(string.Empty, chars);
byte result = Convert.ToByte(binaryString, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us start easy,

We do a loop, check if we have a `'1'`, and if we do, we want to add that bit to the result…

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

byte result = 0;
byte current = 1;
for (var index = 0; index < chars.Length; index++)
{
    if (chars[index] == '1')
    {
        result += current;
    }

    current *= 2;
}

Console.WriteLine(result); // 198
```

Let us check… `198` in binary is… `11000110`. Ah, you see, I assumed that the first index was the least valuable bit, and thus I got it in reverse. So, let us flip that.

By the way, I'm declaring `result` as `byte`, which also presupposes that the array has at most 8 items. For the following code I'll assume the array has exactly 8 items.

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

byte result = 0;
byte current = 1;
for (var index = 0; index < chars.Length; index++)
{
    if (chars[index] == '1')
    {
        result += current;
    }

    current *= 2;
}

Console.WriteLine(result); // 99
```

Check, `99` is `1100011` in binary. Let us codify that assumption, shall we?

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

if (chars.Length != 8)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

byte result = 0;
byte current = 128;
for (var index = 0; index < 8; index++)
{
    if (chars[index] == '1')
    {
        result += current;
    }

    current /= 2;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Alright, we can now reverse the loop for a micro-optimization.

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

if (chars.Length != 8)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

byte result = 0;
byte current = 1;
for (var index = 7; index >= 0; index--)
{
    if (chars[index] == '1')
    {
        result += current;
    }

    current *= 2;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Let us do binary shifts instead of multiplying by 2.

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

if (chars.Length != 8)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

byte result = 0;
byte current = 1;
for (var index = 7; index >= 0; index--)
{
    if (chars[index] == '1')
    {
        result += current;
    }

    current <<= 1;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Let us add another assumption: the array only has `'0'` and `'1'`:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

if (chars.Length != 8)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

for (var index = 7; index >= 0; index--)
{
    if (chars[index] != '0' && chars[index] != '1')
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}

byte result = 0;
byte current = 1;
for (var index = 7; index >= 0; index--)
{
    if (chars[index] == '1')
    {
        result += current;
    }

    current <<= 1;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

You can, of course, remove the validation if you can guarantee that by other means. I'll assume you do that.

Next, let us notice that when we cast `char` to `int` (which is a safe cast to do), `'0'` will be `48` and `'1'` will be `49`. These values differ only in the last (least valued) bit, and that bit is the value we want.

Knowing that, I can set the bit directly:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

byte result = 0;
byte current = 1;
for (var index = 7; index >= 0; index--)
{
    result |= unchecked((byte)(current * (chars[index] & 1)));
    current <<= 1;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In the code above I extract `0` or `1` from the character code (`48` or `49`) using a binary mask `& 1`. Then multiply that by `current`. So we set the current bit if we found a `1`, and we don't if we found a `0`.

Well, we can shift directly, save us a variable.

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

byte result = 0;
for (var index = 7; index >= 0; index--)
{
    result |= unchecked((byte)((1 << (7 - index)) * (chars[index] & 1)));
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In the code above, I don't keep `current`, instead I compute it each iteration.

We can do that without the multiplication. We shift the `0` or `1` instead.

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

byte result = 0;
for (var index = 7; index >= 0; index--)
{
    result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[index] & 1) << (7 - index))));
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In the above, I shift the `0` or `1` that came from the character code. Saving us a multiplication.

Let us unroll the for, we know there are always 8 iterations.

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

byte result = 0;

result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[7] & 1) << (7 - 7))));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[6] & 1) << (7 - 6))));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[5] & 1) << (7 - 5))));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[4] & 1) << (7 - 4))));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[3] & 1) << (7 - 3))));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[2] & 1) << (7 - 2))));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[1] & 1) << (7 - 1))));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[0] & 1) << (7 - 0))));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

We can simplify that a little:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

byte result = 0;

result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[7] & 1) << 0)));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[6] & 1) << 1)));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[5] & 1) << 2)));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[4] & 1) << 3)));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[3] & 1) << 4)));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[2] & 1) << 5)));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[1] & 1) << 6)));
result |= unchecked((byte)(((chars[0] & 1) << 7)));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

How about we do that in a single operation and cast to `byte` at the end?

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};

byte result = unchecked((byte)(
    ((chars[7] & 1) << 0)
    | ((chars[6] & 1) << 1)
    | ((chars[5] & 1) << 2)
    | ((chars[4] & 1) << 3)
    | ((chars[3] & 1) << 4)
    | ((chars[2] & 1) << 5)
    | ((chars[1] & 1) << 6)
    | ((chars[0] & 1) << 7)
));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Excelent! So, we extract `0` or `1` from the character code (using a mask), and shift it position in the byte, put it all together and we have our result. Hopefully it makes sense both how it works and how we got there.

Answer (score 1):

you can use bit operator for it:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' , '1', '1'};
byte theResult=0;
foreach(char ch in chars)
{
    byte bit=byte.Parse(ch.ToString());
    theResult=(byte)(theResult<<1);
    theResult+=bit;
}
```

here https://rextester.com/FXQOJ83728 you can test my code.

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that if a char in the input array is not `'0'` it is to be treated as `'1'`, you can use Linq to calculate the byte as follows:

```
byte b = chars
    .Select((c, i) => (byte)(c == '0' ? 0 : 1 << (7-i))) // Convert each char to a power of 2.
    .Aggregate((byte)0, (b1, b2) => (byte)(b1 | b2));    // OR all the converted values together.
```

Note that the shift is `<<(7-i)` rather than just `<< i` because the MSB (most significant bit) is first.

[Try it on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KrCw7j)

To be honest, I wouldn't use Linq for this. I'd just do:

```
byte b = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    if (chars[i] != '0')
        b |= (byte)(1 << 7 - i);
```

[Try it on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TzTDDi)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(chars);
```

Comment: This answer is not true. It extracts ascii code of 0 and 1 charaters.